# Insert data from API into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, import.io

I retrieve data from an API and I want to get it in my bootstrap layout.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=<myKey>'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var html = "";
  $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
    html += "<div class='row'>";
    html += "<div class='item'><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></div>";
    html += "<span class='item-description'>" + item.description + "</span>";
    html += "</div>";
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container").append(html);
  }, 1500);
});
```

I tried this, but it is not working? why?

Comment: What specifically is not working? The data fetch or modifying the HTML? Also, it seems you have an extra `&` at the end of your url. Is that a typo?

Comment: Oh, and never put your API key into a public post - that information should be private to you only. I removed it from the post, and you should probably generate a new one.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst ok i forgot about the api key thank you!

Comment: @MatthewHerbst fetching the data works like a charm, but i want a bootstrap layout with .row and .item

Answer (score 1):

Well, just add a container to your DOM where the markup should be added.

```
<div class="js-table-container"></div>
```

And then add the html to this container

```
var html = "";
$.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
html += "<div class='row'>";
html += "<div class='item'><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></div>";
html += "<span class='item-description'>" + item.description + "</span>";
html += "</div>";
});
$('.js-table-container').html(html);
```

If i understand your problem correctly, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you what this data to come after or before an element in Dom use jquery insertAfter or insertBefore. Why are you using timeout function?
You can directly add to Dom after processing.

```js
>     $.ajax({
>       url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=<myKey>'
>     }).done(function(data) {
>       console.log(data);
>     
>       var html = "";
>       $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
>         html += "<div class='row'>";
>         html += "<div class='item'><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></div>";
>         html += "<span class='item-description'>" + item.description + "</span>";
>         html += "</div>";
>       });
>     // if you want to load all data inside this container use html
>         $(".container").html(html);
>     // if you want to load after this
>      $(".container").insertAfter(html);
>     // if you want before this
>      $(".container").insertBefore(html);
```